# SDL Web8 : synchronous loading of the UserSettings is deprecated. Please switch to asynchronous loading

Tags: web8, sdl-tridion

When I open CME and I got browser Console warning message"[SDL Web warning] Tridion.ContentManager.UserSettings.getJsonUserSettings: synchronous loading of the UserSettings is deprecated. Please switch to asynchronous loading.".

I want to resolve this warning message. any one have idea which I want to implement logic or setup configuration.

[image]

Comment: If you click the blue link on the right this will take you to the line of code that is prompting the error; is this related to some extension code of your own?

Comment: It does look related to an extension. I don't have an 8.1 environment to verify, but can confirm I don't see this in 8.3 or 8.5

Comment: it`s SDL Web8.1 environment

Comment: Did you try what Saunders recommended in his comment? Is it related to an extension?

Comment: @NunoLinhares I see this in Web 8.5 as well. This doesn't look like its coming from any extension.