# Alternative to UserSettings to get login user info which is deprecated?

Tags: sdl-tridion

Currently we got plugin which gets the UserInfo using UserSettings which seems to be deprecated.

Are there any alternative to **UserSettings** to get logged in user info?

```
Tridion.UI.UserSettings.getJsonUserSettings(true).User.Data.GroupMemberships.some(e => e["@title"] === "CMS Tools Users");
```

(Its working till now but seems to be problematic for future)

Comment: Binod  can you please provide the Tridion version you are using ,  are you  doing any upgrade , if so can you provide the tridion version that you are upgrading

Comment: Also let us know where you are using this , I assume UI Extension etc.

Comment: currently we using tridion verision 8.5.0 and yes we are using it for UI extension (.js)

Comment: the problem is with 8.5.0 or you have issue with the higher version like ( Sites 9.x)

Comment: Binod, please refer to this link https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16175/sdl-web8-synchronous-loading-of-the-usersettings-is-deprecated-please-switch (  not sure if you are facing similar issue). Can you share the Error message for us to review and get back to you.

Comment: Binod , can you share the error details